# Firefox RootStore cert8.db/key3.db not existing

Tags: firefox, nss, certutil

I want to access the Firefox Root Store under Windows (7) with Firefox 45.0.1. I found several sources that told me to navigate to C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\8ab3jkih.default\cert8.db.
Unfortunately I can't find cert8.db, although 8ab3jkih.default is present (and the only folder).
I tried accessing the DB with certutil, which works, but only gives me 4 certificates for -viewstore (should be about 150). Afterwards I tried accessing -getconfig and -databaselocations, but that just tells me that the system can't find the given file. I hoped to find the location of the database.
Yes, I already heard of NSS, but figured I should try it manually first, before working with it.

Is there anything wrong with my installation? Should I try to reinstall? What else can I do? My endgame btw is finding out whether a certain given certificate is a root certificate, so I just want to programmatically access the list of root certificates and compare them to the given cert.

Comment: In your profile directory, what else do you have? If you don't have `cert8.db`, `key3.db`, etc, it may not be your profile directory.  "Help" - "Support" (or something like that) shows you the profile directory. Or just type in direction bar: `about:support`.

Comment: Thanks, apparently it is somewhere else now. Could find the position in the about:support interface.

Comment: OK I try to make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure you have correctly located your Firefox profile directory.

You can open the menu in Firefox (the three horizontal bars button), find the <kbd>Help</kbd>, then go to <kbd>Troubleshooting information...</kbd>. In this page, you can see the <kbd>Profile directory</kbd> button. Press it and there you go.

Or, another way to open this page, is to type in the direction bar:

```
about:support
```